# Expressjs use request body from REST Api

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, express

I am experimenting with nodejs / expressjs for our webclient and am having trouble passing the data to my .ejs template:

I have an REST API call to our application server which returns a json element. I was hoping I could call the API directly in the router and pass it as a variable to my template but I can't seem get extract the json element. I know I could use an ajax call directly in the template, but I wanted to try to stick to an MVC Design pattern.

returning the json element to a local variable which I then pass doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I've been scouring the internet the entire day trying to find an answer, but in all the tutorials all I've seen is everyone just logging their result. That's all well and good but it would be nice to do something with it.

`

```
    var url = "http://application.server"

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); //returns Json element, how can I extract this??
  });

  res.render('index', {
    //data: body <---- I want to pass the JSON element to my template here
  });

    });
```

`

thank you!!!!

Comment: Why don't you just call `res.render` within the callback you give to `request()`?

Comment: yeah, I don't know why I didn't just do that..... It works perfectly :) 

I think I should just go home for the day.

Thank you Phil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Phil Thanks for the completely logical answer :)

I now render my template within the callback and parse `body`to a JSON object with `JSON.parse(body)`. Later I will have to make more API calls and pass them but for our prototype this works.

```
var url = "http://application.server"

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    res.render('index', {data:JSON.parse(body)});
  });
});
```

Comment: If you need to start making more API calls you might find using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library (`async.parallel`) or promisifying your API calls and using `Promise.all` will help when you need to aggregate multiple async calls into one callback.